# GridView - display '0' for all headers when empty data set

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using a GridView to display some ifnromation in ASP.NET. I need it to simply display 0 in the gridview fields (there's only ever one row returned) if the dataset is empty, plus of course display the headers. How do I do this?

Comment: What about adding empty row to DataSet before you bound it to the GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your grid and add the EmptyDataTemplate like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID field" />
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>put whatever you want in here</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes bind a dummy dataset with one row, with all zeros as fields, to the grid with zeros as the field labels.  That would be the best way.